# Pros and cons of using web2py as GUI interface instead of Tkinter,

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, web2py

What do you think, I am not going to build app for sell, but just to build app for the company i work for, app to automate MS office tasks and developing standalone database app to keep track of company equipments

Thanks

Comment: -1 because you have ignored multiple attempts to correct your answer rate.  I am stalking you until you fix it :-)

Answer (score 4):

Not a bad idea. You can [package your web2py app as a standalone binary](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/14#How-to-distribute-your-applications-as-binaries) for Windows and Mac, including its own Python interpreter, web server (Rocket), and database (SQLite). Just click to run (no command line needed).

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, browser based UIs make *your* job as the maintainer easier because deployment is trivial. When you upgrade your server, everyone sees the new version of the application. If you're rolling this out to a lot of people, deployment can be a significant issue.

On the other hand, creating a desktop application using a toolkit like Tkinter (or wxPython, or pyQT, etc) makes *your users* lives easier. This is because desktop applications generally perform faster and have richer widget sets than you can have with a browser.

It's possible to have the best of both words: you can create a desktop app that gets updates over the intranet. I've done this with tcl and tk, it should be equally possible to do with python. It takes a bit more work to set up, but it can be a powerful (and highly underutilized) technique.

Answer (score 2):

web2py and tkinter serve very different purposes, really. With web2py, you must run a webserver, even if you just use a local instance of Rocket, and access the app via a browser. An app built using tkinter runs under your native window manager and stands alone.

Comment: I heard that it is with built web server and comes with python

Comment: @user610961, web2py comes with python compiled into MS Windows version